# LEFT JOIN with NULL, NOT EQUAL both of them showing unexpected result

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

Get shocked ! What is wrong with following code ? Neither `LEFT JOIN` with `NULL` is selecting `Null` rows, Nor MYSQL `!=` operator is showing only non-matched rows

Two table

Table `book` - lists of books

```
id  |   ttl
===========
1   |   Science
2   |   Math
3   |   English
```

Table `block_book` - lists of book assigned to each block

```
id  |   block|  book
=====================
1   |   1   |   1
2   |   1   |   2
```

Now, requirement is to show the rest of the books that are not assigned to blocks. So what I do

```
SELECT
    book.id AS id, book.ttl AS book 
FROM
    block_book
JOIN
    book ON book.id != block_book.book
GROUP BY book.id
```

With the `!=` operator it should be following result, shouldn't it ? because only the subject `English` is not in table `block_book`

**Expected Result**

```
id  |   book
===========
3   |   English
```

But all books are selected. **Current Result**

```
id  |   book
===========
1   |   Science
2   |   Math
3   |   English
```

I tried with `Left JOIN` with `Null`

```
SELECT
    book.id AS id, book.ttl AS book 
FROM
    block_book
LEFT JOIN
    book ON book.id = block_book.book
WHERE block_book.book IS NULL
```

but it returns nothing

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5c3b/9)

Comment: Hi. Learn what INNER JOIN ON returns: CROSS JOIN rows that satisfy the ON condition. Learn what LEFT JOIN returns: INNER JOIN rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of a LEFT JOIN. PS What you want to do is an obvious faq. PS It is not very helpful to ask "shouldn't it" unless you explain what & why it "should". It is really a question about your wrong expectations & interpretations, so you have to give them. Your "because" is in the right direction but it's not clear how that plus your code leads to what you expect.

Comment: @philipxy, really appreciable tips

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `right join`.

So this should work:

```
SELECT
book.id AS id, book.ttl AS book 
FROM
block_book
RIGHT JOIN
book ON book.id = block_book.book
WHERE block_book.book IS NULL
```

Or if you want to use `left join`, you should write the query like this:

```
SELECT
book.id AS id, book.ttl AS book 
FROM
book
LEFT JOIN
block_book ON book.id = block_book.book
WHERE block_book.book IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

> Now, requirement is to show the rest of the books that are not assigned to blocks.

The most direct way to approach this is to use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select b.*
from book b
where not exists (select 1
                  from block_book bb
                  where bb.book = b.id
                 );
```

Comment: Would `NOT EXISTS` be faster than `JOIN` ?

Comment: @AnandaLC . . . That depends on the database.  It should not be slower, but both might implement the sample underlying algorithm.  I suggest this because it is almost a direct translation of your question.